# get rid of tiny fraction in bar plot scale (Pandas/Python)

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

When I'm trying to plot a bar plot (of histograms), using `pd.cut`, I get a funny (and very annoying!) `0.001` added to the axis (from the left), making it starting from `-1.001` instead of `-1`. The question is how to get rid of this? (please see the figure).

My code is:

```
out_i = pd.cut(df, bins=np.arange(-1,1.2,0.2), include_lowest=True)
out_i.value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar(rot=45, figsize=(6,6))
plt.tight_layout()
```

with df:

```
             a 
0    -0.402203
1    -0.019031
2    -0.979292
3    -0.701221
4    -0.267261
5    -0.563602
7    -0.454961
8     0.632456
9    -0.843081
10   -0.629253
11   -0.946188
12   -0.628178
13   -0.776933
14   -0.717091
15   -0.392144
16   -0.799408
17   -0.897951
18    0.255321
19   -0.641854
20   -0.356393
21   -0.507321
22   -0.698238
23   -0.985097
25   -0.661444
26   -0.751593
27   -0.437505
28   -0.413451
29   -0.798745
30   -0.736440
31   -0.672727
32   -0.807688
33   -0.087085
34   -0.393203
35   -0.979730
36   -0.902951
37   -0.454231
38   -0.561951
39   -0.388580
40   -0.706501
41   -0.408248
42   -0.377235
43   -0.283110
44   -0.517428
45   -0.949603
46   -0.268667
47   -0.376199
48   -0.472293
49   -0.211781
50   -0.921520
51   -0.345870
53   -0.542487
55   -0.597996
```

[image]

Comment: Do you completely want to get rid of the x-axis labels? I can't really see a `0.001` on the axis.

Comment: @JanTrienes, if you notice, the X scale starts with -1.001, instead of -1 which is specified by `bins`. I want my x ticks to be exactly as defined by `bins`. Also, there is `-2.22e-16` instead of `0`.

Comment: Try `pd.cut(..., include_lowest=False)`. Using that, I get the following intervals: `[(-1.0, -0.8] < (-0.8, -0.6] < (-0.6, -0.4] < (-0.4, -0.2] ... (0.2, 0.4] < (0.4, 0.6] < (0.6, 0.8] < (0.8, 1.0]]`

Comment: @JanTrienes, you are right, but then it misses the exact values of `-1` if there are present in the data frame (however in my case there are not). I am curious how to include the lowest values and do not get the annoying `0.001`.

Comment: so you want a left-closed interval starting at -1. `right=False`. The `-2.22e-16` is a floating point rounding error (-1 + 5* 0.2 != 0)

Comment: Would it be acceptable to just chop off everything starting from the second decimal for the plot?

Comment: @JanTrienes, that's interesting! Need to explore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it is acceptable to chop off the decimal points of the intervals, generate a custom list of interval labels and set this as the `xticklabels` of the plot:

```
out_i = pd.cut(df['a'], bins=np.arange(-1,1.2,0.2), include_lowest=True)

intervals = out_i.cat.categories
labels = ['(%.1f, %.1f]' % (int(interval.left*100)/100, interval.right) for interval in intervals]

ax = out_i.value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar(rot=45, figsize=(6,6))
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Which results in the following plot:

[image]

**Note:** this will always output a half-closed interval `(a,b]`. It can be improved by making the brackets dynamic as per the parameters of `pd.cut`.

Comment: thanks! But what happens when I have exact values of `-1` and `1` ? This plot should represent the distribution of correlation coefficients, and they certainly may get values of -1,1.

Comment: @ArnoldKlein the distribution and the actual bins remain unchanged, only the labels where changed. So a value of -1 will be associated to the `-1, -0.8` bin.

Comment: Oh, I see! My bad. Sure, what an amazing solution! Thanks! So nothings has changes except the labels. Fab!